# Symmetric nonnegative matrix factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex, matrix-factorization

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}$ is symmetric.  I would like to factorize $A\approx UU^\top$ by solving
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_U & \sum_{ij} \left(A_{ij}\ln\frac{A_{ij}}{[UU^\top]_{ij}}+[UU^\top]_{ij} \right)\\
\textrm{s.t.} & U\geq0,
\end{array}
$$
for a local minimizer.

The objective of this problem is KL divergence $\mathrm{KL}(A|UU^\top)$, similar to the one used in [this paper](http://perso.uclouvain.be/paul.vandooren/publications/HoV08.pdf) and others on nonnegative matrix factorization.  The difference is that I want to optimize as $UU^\top$ rather than $UV^\top$ for matrices $U$ and $V$.

I can't find papers on this variation of nonnegative factorization, except [this paper](http://perso.uclouvain.be/paul.vandooren/publications/HoV08.pdf) mentions it briefly under eq.(11) without discussion.  As I understand it, convergence of nonnegative matrix factorization algorithms is well-understood, and I'm hoping to find something similar.

Any ideas for how to find a local optimizer using a simple iteration?  Ideally, I'm hoping some method with nice convergence (e.g. multiplicative updates) from nonnegative matrix factorization will be applicable without much adaptation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going through some of my old StackExchange posts and came across this one.  As it turns out, the answer led to a section in [a published paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jsolomon/assets/gw.pdf)!

As detailed in that paper (and in its notation), if you wish to minimize $\mathrm{KL}(B|AA^\top)$, the following iterations will decrease the objective---and in practice work well---
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
U_k&\gets A_k\otimes[(B\oslash AA^\top)A]\\
A_{k+1}&\gets U\cdot\mathrm{diag}[1\oslash
\sqrt{U^\top\mathbf{1}}]
\end{array}
$$
Here, $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the vector of all ones, $\otimes$ denotes elementwise multiplication, and $\oslash$ denotes elementwise division.   $A$ should be initialized using random entries.

Comment: That's super cool!